# Getting the DOM element from a JQuery object in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7

I'm attempting to get the DOM counterpart of a JQuery object in order to set the onclick since IE7 doesn't support .attr('onclick').

However I'm having a fair bit of trouble:

```
var button0 = $('#idElement').next().find('input').get(0);
var originalOnClick = button0.onclick;
var newOnClick = function() {
    return false;
}
button0.onclick = newOnClick;
```

Button0 is undefined, and I'm not sure why. get(0) should get the dom element.

```
<select id="idElement">(Bunch of options here)</select>
<div>
        <input type="button"/>
</div>
```

Comment: How is your dom looks? Could you post relevant html markup too? What about chrome and ff does this code works, you have not mentioned in your post. if that is undefined then **surely the next element does not contain that input.**

Comment: I added the relevant markup.

Comment: $('#idElement').next().find('input') works under Chrome and Firefox. It finds the input element I want to fetch. I don't think .find() works under Internet Explorer 7

Comment: Your jQuery version should not have to be `2.0+` this version does not support IE legacy browsers 6,7,8. Make sure to load jQuery version 1.0+. Or you can use `jQuery's migrate plugin too.`.

Comment: I'm currently using 1.11.1. What Coby posted works though, whereas .find() fails to find anything in IE7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var newOnClick = function(){
    return false;
};

var $input = $('#idElement + div input');

$input[0].setAttribute('onclick','');
$input.on('click', newOnClick);
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tBV7A/